# When ListView item gets out of visible scope

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView that I populate with images. I also use AsynTask to load the images in the background to not disturb the UI thread.

But there is one problem. When I scroll, for example to the 50th item, all items get populated so I have to wait for the ones that are visible.

Is there a way to block execution of the getView method for items that aren't visible anymore?

Comment: no. but you can query the visibility (isShown) of the item in the asynctask.

Comment: You could cancel the AsyncTask for items that lost visibility.